# Could Antarctic Vibranium destroy Captain America’s shield?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, vibranium

So we know that Captain America’s shield is made from a Wakandan Vibranium-steel alloy that can only be destroyed by the strongest of forces (Doctor Doom used the power of the Beyonder to fire a Beam From Out of the Blue that killed many characters but only broke a piece off of the shield) but could Antarctic Vibranium (also known as anti-metal) dissolve the shield?

Comment: the Antarctic-Vibranium produces vibrations that completely weaken a metal at a molecular level. So considering a shield made of vibranium-steel alloy (and not pure vibranium), it would definitely be damaged. However the pure vibranium shield would be strong enough to absorb the vibrations and stay put.

Comment: I thought it was proto-adamantium, not vibranium-steel...

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Vulnerability of Adamantium and Vibranium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180412/vulnerability-of-adamantium-and-vibranium)

Comment: @Edlothiad for the record, that is specifically asking about magic, not anti-metal

Comment: @AncientSwordRage in which case it's related and one can ignore the possibility of the dupe.

Answer (score 3):

From Black Panther vol 3 #29, where Black Panther defeats Klaw in his sonic form

[image: Black Panther uses a frequency modulator attached to a pure vibranium ceremonial knife, to attack a being of pure sonic energy - Ulysses Klaw]

Well if Antarctic Vibranium can't affect its Wakandan cousin, then it probably won't affect an alloy of Wakandan Vibranium. Therefore it would not destroy Captain America's shield.

Answer (score 2):

Based on these images of Captain America Vol 1 #417, the barge shown below has anti-metal on it.

[image: Captain America notes the barge carrying anti-metal is made of plastic, as Ka-Za (Kevin Plunder) explains, a metal boat would be melted.]

Below you can see Captain America's shield on a pile of the anti-metal and it didn't subsequently melt.

[image: Captain America and Ka-Za throw lumps of anti-metal at a giant robot. In the background Captain America's shield is wedged between lumps of the rocks. The Robot reaches down to grab the two heros, and in the process touches the anti-metal in the plastic barge and it's hand begins to vibrate out of existance]